# SMTP Services on Windows7

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, iis-7.5

i read here in other threads that Windows 7 does not include the SMTP service anymore, so it doesn't have a local SMTP server. all threads directed the Questioners to other, 3rd party SMTP services. The question is: is there any other way of configuring a local SMTP server yet? or is it still an open issue, and i have no choice but to use a 3rd party software?

Comment: After some googling i found that we can add SMTP server after installing "Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7 with Service Pack 1 (SP1)". But when i go to install this i encounter some error : "installer encountered an error : 0x8007000d  The Data is Invalid". Is there any clue for this ?

Comment: that error sounds like the installer might not have downloaded without errors, try downloading again :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows 7 doesn't have a smtp service only other way I could find that you could set up a Microsoft smtp server would be using "IIS6 management console" which comes after installing "Remote Server Administration Tools". From what I read you cannot install Remote Server Administration Tools on Windows 7 with SP1 but seeing your comment I guess there is a version specifically for SP1.

Using a 3rd party *smtp server for production* I would recommend [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/index.php?page=download). It's free and recommended on a lot of posts about free smtp. Before using .net to connect to it you will need to setup [Domain and Accounts](http://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/v5.3/?page=basic_configuration) for it to work.

If you just need a *smtp server for testing* you could use [smtp4dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/releases/view/71614).

> Windows 7/Vista/XP/2003/2010 compatible dummy SMTP server. Sits in the
>   system tray and does not deliver the received messages. The received
>   messages can be quickly viewed, saved and the source/structure
>   inspected. Useful for testing/debugging software that generates email.